# Task показывает одинаковую итерацию в цикле - C#

Tags: c#, task

Добрый вечер, пытаюсь с помощью Task создать несколько процессов и запустить функцию в каждом из них, но всегда получается одинаковая итерация. Вот пример кода:

```
 var Task_1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
             {
                 for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                 {
                     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine(i);

                         //Task.Factory.StartNew(matrix.Multiplication, i, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

                     }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

                 }
             });

            Task.WaitAll(Task_1);
```

На экране не выводится 7 различных цифр в какой-либо последовательности, при последней компиляции вывелась одна четверка и все остальные семерки. Объясните кто-нибудь в чем проблема и как это обойти? Я пробовал в цикле ожидать завершении каждого процесса (пример: task.Wait()), но тогда уже ведь задача не является параллельной.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `i` — **переменная**! А значит, её значение меняется. Когда задача начинает выполняться, значение `i` уже вполне может измениться. А вы ведь выводите всё время одну и ту же переменную `i`.

Я бы написал так:

```
Task Output(int i)
{
    return Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}

var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    tasks.Add(Output(i));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

При этом значение `i` копируется в момент вызова функции.

Answer (score 1):

В свое время сталкивался с этой проблемой. Объяснение нашел на английском SO. К сожалению не могу найти ссылку. Вынесите переменную в локальную итерацию, примерно так:

```
var th = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
             {
                 for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                 {
                     int localVar = i;

                     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine(localVar);

                     }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score -3):

Спасибо всем, вроде разобрался, решил проблему следующим образом:

```
                var Task_1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
             {

                     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                     {

                         for (int j = 0; j <= Environment.ProcessorCount - 1; j++)
                         {

                             Console.WriteLine(j);
                             //Task.Factory.StartNew(matrix.Multiplication, j, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

                         }


                     }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);


             });


            Task.WaitAll(Task_1);
```

Comment: Зачем же вам в таком случае `Task`, если вы все делаете последовательно?

Comment: Видимо, я запутался